# Saving a text file created using VBA in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, txt

I found VBA code that will create a text file out of the body of an Outlook email.

It does not save the text file.

How do I save the created text file?

```vb
Sub ExportUrlToTextFileFromEmail()
    'UpdatebyExtendoffice20220413
    Dim xMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim xRegExp As RegExp
    Dim xMatchCollection As MatchCollection
    Dim xMatch As Match
    Dim xUrl As String, xSubject As String, xFileName As String
    Dim xFs As FileSystemObject
    Dim xTextFile As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim InvalidArr
    
    If Application.ActiveWindow.Class = olInspector Then
        Set xMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    ElseIf Application.ActiveWindow.Class = olExplorer Then
        Set xMail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    End If
    Set xRegExp = New RegExp
    With xRegExp
        .Pattern = "(https?[:]//([0-9a-z=\?:/\.&-^!#$;_])*)"
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With
    If xRegExp.test(xMail.Body) Then
        InvalidArr = Array("/", "\", "*", ":", Chr(34), "?", "<", ">", "|")
        xSubject = xMail.Subject
        For i = 0 To UBound(InvalidArr)
            xSubject = VBA.Replace(xSubject, InvalidArr(i), "")
        Next i
        xFileName = "Z:\" & xSubject & ".txt"
        Set xFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set xTextFile = xFs.CreateTextFile(xFileName, True)
        xTextFile.WriteLine (vbCrLf)
        Set xMatchCollection = xRegExp.Execute(xMail.Body)
        i = 0
        For Each xMatch In xMatchCollection
            xUrl = xMatch.SubMatches(0)
            i = i + 1
            'xTextFile.WriteLine (i & ". " & xUrl & vbCrLf)
            xTextFile.WriteLine (xUrl & vbCrLf)
        Next
        xTextFile.Close
        Set xTextFile = Nothing
        Set xMatchCollection = Nothing
        Set xFs = Nothing
        Set xFolderItem = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(0).ParseName(xFileName)
        xFolderItem.InvokeVerbEx ("open")
        Set xFolderItem = Nothing
    End If
    Set xRegExp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I tried `xTextfile.save`.

---

With `On Error Resume Next` removed, I get

> run time error "Object variable or with block variable not set"

on `xTextFile.WriteLine (xUrl & vbCrLf)`.

Comment: Remove the `On Error Resume Next` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i got a run time error when i removed this line "Objexct variable or with block variable not set", i tried removing the next part as well FWIW.

Comment: If you're getting an error, it's useful to tell us which line has that error.

Comment: sorry, got the error on the xTextFile.WriteLine (xUrl & vbCrLf) line

Comment: But this line `xTextFile.WriteLine (vbCrLf)` succeeds?

Answer (score 0):

The code you found is trying to create the text file in the root of a Z drive

```
xFileName = "Z:\" & xSubject & ".txt"
```

Perhaps you don't have a Z drive on your computer, or you don't have access to save a file to the root of the Z drive.

Try changing this line to where you actually want to save the file, similar to:

```
xFileName = "C:\Users\yourusername\Documents\" & xSubject & ".txt"
```

Comment: thanks, i do have access but the file  doesnt save once created for some reason

Answer (score 0):

A `SubMatches` collection contains individual submatch strings, and can only be created using the `Execute` method of the `RegExp` object. When a regular expression is executed, zero or more submatches can result when subexpressions are enclosed in capturing parentheses. Each item in the `SubMatches` collection is the string found and captured by the regular expression.

Try to use the `Debug.Print` statement to see what results you have got in the code:

```
 For Each xMatch In xMatchCollection
      xUrl = xMatch.SubMatches(0)
      i = i + 1
      Debug.Print(xUrl & vbCrLf)
Next
```